I can't perform gradual scrolling in my .NET Maui App
I am new to .NET Maui and I am creating my first application that first checks the dll file for interface implementation, then the user enters a number and the program should output all prime numbers up to it. The problem came up in the visualization, I have the application itself hangs when a large number is processed, so I decided to make it asynchronous. This didn't help, because the visualization itself hangs when it tries to list these numbers. Then I decided to add gradual scrolling, but it doesn't work. In the debug this event just doesn't work.
This is MainPage.xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PrimeNumApp"
             x:Class="PrimeNumApp.MainPage">
    
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Padding="30,0"
            Spacing="25">
            <Label
                Text="Cписок простых чисел"
                Style="{StaticResource Headline}"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1" />
            <Image 
                Source="kitten.gif"
                HeightRequest="200" 
                HorizontalOptions="Center"  
                IsAnimationPlaying="True" />
            <Entry
                x:Name="NumberEntry"
                Placeholder="Введите число" />
            <StackLayout
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                Spacing="5"
                >
                <Button
                    x:Name="LoadBtn"
                    Text="Загрузить сборку" 
                    Clicked="OnLoadClicked"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    BackgroundColor="Gray" />
                <Button
                    x:Name="StartBtn"
                    Text="Посчитать"
                    Clicked="OnStartClicked"
                    IsEnabled="False"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    BackgroundColor="DarkRed" />
            </StackLayout>
            <CollectionView x:Name="PrimeNumCollection"
                            
                            RemainingItemsThreshold="5"
                            RemainingItemsThresholdReached="OnCollectionViewRemainingItemsThresholdReached">
                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" />
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding}"
                  TextColor="White"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
        </VerticalStackLayout>

</ContentPage>


This is MainPage.xaml.cs
using Contract;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;

namespace PrimeNumApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _isImplemented;
        private Assembly _assembly;
        private string _realizationPath;
        private IPrimeGenerator _primeNumberGenerator;
        private const int PageSize = 5;
        private int _currentPage = 0;
        public ObservableCollection<int> DisplayablePrimeNums { get; set; }
        private List<int> _allPrimeNumbers = new List<int>();
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DisplayablePrimeNums = new ObservableCollection<int>();
            PrimeNumCollection.ItemsSource = DisplayablePrimeNums;
            PrimeNumCollection.RemainingItemsThresholdReached += OnCollectionViewRemainingItemsThresholdReached;
            

        }
        public async void OnStartClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(NumberEntry.Text, out int number))
            {
                try
                {
                    _allPrimeNumbers = await Task.Run(() => _primeNumberGenerator!.GetPrimeNumbers(number));
                    DisplayablePrimeNums.Clear();
                    LoadNextPage();
                    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Ошибка", ex.Message, "OK");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Ошибка", "Вы ввели не натуральное число", "OK");
            }
                        
        }
        private void LoadNextPage()
        {
            foreach (int number in _allPrimeNumbers.GetRange(_currentPage, PageSize))
            {
                DisplayablePrimeNums.Add(number);
            }

            _currentPage += PageSize;
        }
        public void OnCollectionViewRemainingItemsThresholdReached(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadNextPage();
        }
        public async void OnLoadClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await PickDll();
        }
        private async Task PickDll()
        {
            var customFileType = new FilePickerFileType(
                    new Dictionary<DevicePlatform, IEnumerable<string>>
                    {
                    { DevicePlatform.WinUI, new[] { ".dll" } },
                    });

            try
            {
                var result = await FilePicker.PickAsync(new PickOptions()
                {
                    FileTypes = customFileType,
                    PickerTitle = "Выберите файл формата .dll"
                });

                if (result != null)
                {
                    _realizationPath = result.FullPath;
                    await LoadDll();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Ошибка", "Ошибка при загрузке сборки: " + ex.Message, "OK");
            }
        }
        private async Task LoadDll()
        {
            _assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(_realizationPath);
            await CheckContractRealization();
        }
        private async Task CheckContractRealization()
        {
            _isImplemented = _assembly.GetTypes().Any(type => type.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IPrimeGenerator)));
            if (_isImplemented)
            {
                LoadBtn.BackgroundColor = Colors.Green;
                StartBtn.IsEnabled = true;
                StartBtn.BackgroundColor = Colors.Gray;
                var primeGeneratorType = _assembly.GetTypes()
                        .Where(type => typeof(IPrimeGenerator).IsAssignableFrom(type) && type.IsClass)
                        .Select(type => type)
                        .First();

                _primeNumberGenerator = (IPrimeGenerator)Activator.CreateInstance(primeGeneratorType)!;
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Ошибка", "Реализация не соответсвует контракту", "OK");
            }
        }

    }

}


I tried changing and removing the scroller itself, displaying DataTemplate inside CollectionView, it didn't work

You can refer to the doc: ScrollView.

There are multiple issues with the source code provided:

You are loading all the prime numbers at once. So if you add a huge number it will be trying to get the prime numbers at once which is not the best for performance. Incremental loading means loading some amount of data out of bigger chunk and then when you reach end of that data then load more. So you should improve your GetPrimeNumbers to limit it and then when you reach the limit then fetch more.
MAUI provides the functionality to detect if you are about to reach the end of your list using OnCollectionViewRemainingItemsThresholdReached and then fetch more data. Few issues there for you. You already declare the event in xaml but also do it in the constructor. So only do it once. And then if for example you get first 20 prime numbers then when you reach last 5, the method OnCollectionViewRemainingItemsThresholdReached will be invoked where you can load 20 more prime numbers.
Another issue is organisation of code and not Binding to properties. follow a MVVM pattern to bind to correct properties.

